# Correct Way To Find things in Pydev Anacondas py33

Tags: python, pydev, python-3.3, cookiejar, anaconda

I am using PyDev to develop some Python software.

My environment is Anacondas, Python 3.3

Just now, I wanted to use the cookiejar module.

The online tutorials state that I need to import the module using

```
import cookiejar
```

However, that did not work.  After searching through my files, I discovered that I needed to use:

```
import http.cookiejar
```

I am pretty sure that I am not supposed to have to search through my file system in order to find a module.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My environment was set incorrectly, and I was actually using Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.2.

Some of the classes for Python 3.3 have been placed into packages, which is why I need http.cookiejar instead of cookiejar.  To find these, I need to look up documentation specific to 3.3, rather than 2.7.  e.g.  http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.cookiejar.html